# How can I view thumbnails of pictures?

Tags: filesystem

How can I copy the attributes of the pictures folder so that 
I can view thumbnails of pictures on, for example, network drives?

Comment: For those that also want to quickly do basic picture edits like crop and rotation, also consider Nomacs: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211087/software-to-seamlessly-edit-multiple-images/1292048#1292048 Related: https://superuser.com/questions/54841/picture-thumbnails-on-ubuntu | https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25978/image-viewer-for-multiple-images

Answer (score 33):

This is just a setting in Nautilus.  The default setting are designed to improve network performance.  However, you can change Nautilus to display preview thumbnails of remote image files...

1. Open Nautilus
2. From the menubar, select Edit
3. Select Preferences
4. In the File Preferences dialog, Click on the Preview tab
5. From the Files drop down, make sure "Always" is selected, instead of "Local Files Only"
6. Optional: You might want to change the maximum file size that thumbnail previews are shown for

[image]

**Update for Ubuntu 20.04 (Nautilus 3.36)**

1. Click the menu button in the header bar
2. Click "Preferences"
3. The "Preferences" dialog will appear
4. Click the "Search & Preview" tab
5. In the "Thumbnails" section, select "All files" radio button
6. Optionally select the file size to generate thumbnails for, using the "Only for files smaller than" spinner.
7. Close the "Preferences" dialog

[image: Preferences Dialog in Ubuntu 20.04]

Comment: This solution no longer works in Ubuntu 20.04. There is no Edit menu.

Comment: Updated with instructions for Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Thanks, that works.

Comment: In Ubuntu 22.04.01 I have the same problem and cannot find this preference and edit button.

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't find the "edit" menu from [PJ Singh's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/539911/56280), but adapting it to the command line worked for me:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/show-image-thumbnails '"always"'
```

Note the double quoting: it seems `dconf` wants a quoted string. To find the appropriate setting and to set it you can also use the `dconf-editor` GUI.

Comment: The Edit menu no longer appears in Nautilus in Ubuntu 20.04. The commandline worked. I upvoted this solution.