# Software to seamlessly edit multiple images

Tags: 18.04, software-recommendation, image-processing

Format of my mom's old PC is overdue, W7 is slow and choppy and I'd love to show her how fast her laptop can be with a lightweight Ubuntu distro.

But my mom is really used to Microsoft Office Picture Manager 2007. From time to time she has to sit and crop/rotate/change brightness or contrast/resize (as in, lowering the quality)/delete multiple images.
And MOPM 2007 has this really neat option, that after launching a file from a directory and editing it, you can just press an arrow, which seamlessly opens next image in same window, while remembering actions done on previous one.

That way she can edit those photos really fast and easy. No saving every image separately. No opening files separately. No pop-ups every action. 
Do your job and save all at the end of work-session. Obviously I can't introduce her to something like GIMP, but in the other hand I worry all those light editors might be too lite.

So, before I start looking on my own, going through tens of different programs - maybe someone can suggest something first?

Answer (score 1):

**Nomacs**

https://github.com/nomacs/nomacs

I was looking for something to replace Google Photos locally to help organize my photos.

I need to quickly browse image thumbnails and do basic edit operations like renaming, rotation and cropping, and Nomacs fit perfectly!

When you open a directory with:

```
sudo apt install nomacs
nomacs .
```

you get thumbnails like this:

[image]

Double click on an image and it becomes big:

[image]

Then from there you can:

- Shift-T: back to thumbnails
- Left Right arrow keys: move to previous / next photo
- C: crop with mouse. Once done:

  - Enter: apply the crop
  - Esc: abort the crop
  - Ctrl + Shift + S: save cropped image as a new file
  - Ctrl + S: overwrite original file
  - Ctrl + Z: undo edit
- R: rotate
- F2: rename

Here's what crop mode looks like for example:

[image]

Some shortcomings:

- doesn't support videos: https://github.com/nomacs/nomacs/issues/191
- can't scan directories recursively: https://github.com/nomacs/nomacs/issues/297

Tested in Ubuntu 19.04, nomacs 3.12.

Answer (score 0):

By Rawstudio you can easily edit jpeg files, too. But I am not sure, if you are able to install it to current Ubuntu releases.
https://rawstudio.org/